# How to diagnose the fault of a laptop that sometimes doesn't boot?

Tags: boot, laptop, hardware-failure

I've an old Samsung NC-10 but sometimes it doesn't boot. The power led turns on and I hear the fan but the monitor is black and nothing happen.

If I try many times to reboot then after many attempts it works normally and I can use it. How can I make a good diagnosis of the problem?

So far I've tried:

- remove the battery
- use an external monitor
- reinstall the OS

Comment: What LEDs exactly blink?  It may be an error code pointing you to an issue.  I'd try swapping RAM modules around though as a starting point.

Comment: @ultrasawblade thanks for the help. In fact when it doesn't work only alimentation led switch on and stay on. I will try to make my question more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem on my notebook ever since I changed my processor a few weeks ago. RAM is ok, processor is ok, motherboard, hard drive and all hardware is ok. I don't see the cause of the problem other than an **internal current issue**, maybe because the new processor draws more current than the original one, and my notebook runs without a battery. But whatever, for a system diagnosis this is the way to go:

1. Clean it very thoroughly, dust is the #2 cause of problems on old computers (just after water & moisture). Dust may be conductive and cause shorts and it's a heat isolator.
2. Leave your notebook turned on without battery (only A.C.) for ~12 hours. It may be that the CMOS battery must be running low on power and this would help recharge it (or buy another one, they're cheap unless it's some strange type Samsung uses). Be careful, I've had motherboards that literally **die** when the CMOS battery runs completely dry.
3. Get a free copy of memtest86 or memtest86+ (you can run it from any Fedora live cd) and check your RAM modules one by one to see if they're faulty. You can use the BIOS utility to check RAM, but memtest is far better.

Also, when it *doesn't* turn on, do you get backlight or not?

Good luck.